# Is there any default scope separator in OpenMP?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, openmp

I am new to OpenMP, just done my first try,it was a matrix multiplication. I am just wondering if there is a default block separator existed in openMP?
following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define MAX_THREADS 4
#define ASIZE 500

int main()
{
  /*intialization of 2 matrix*/     
  long matrixa [ASIZE][ASIZE];
  long matrixb [ASIZE][ASIZE];
  long matrixc [ASIZE][ASIZE] = {0};
  for(int i=0; i<ASIZE; i++)
    for(int j=0;j<ASIZE; j++)
    {
      matrixa [i][j] = 1;
      matrixb [i][j] = j;
    }

  omp_set_num_threads(MAX_THREADS);

  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    long cprivate [ASIZE][ASIZE] = {0};
    #pragma omp for
    for(int i =0 ;i<ASIZE; i++)
      for(int j=0; j<ASIZE; j++)
        for(int k=0; k<ASIZE; k++)
          cprivate[i][j]+=matrixa[i][k]*matrixb[k][j];

    #pragma omp critical
    for(int i =0 ;i<ASIZE; i++)
      for(int j=0; j<ASIZE; j++)
        matrixc[i][j]+=cprivate[i][j];

    //#pragma omp barrier
    if(omp_get_thread_num() ==0)
      for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
        printf("Snap of C array %lu \n", matrixc[1][i]); //print out chunk of the first row!

  }
}
```

I thought this way cause whether I add the `#pragma omp barrier` or not, I can get the expected result, which should be the result after the complete execution of the `#pragma omp critical` block.

## questions

@ why it makes no difference with or without `#pragma omp barrier`  Any ideas?

@　I also noticed once I Increase the array size to 600 hundred, it will alert segmentation fault when executing the .o file, My initial guess it was from the int range(I have modified the array type from int[] to long[]), no difference.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. I answer your two questions at the end of your question. However, your title is "Is there any default scope separator in OpenMP?". That's another question. What do you mean by "scope seperator"?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is likely failing because you are using automatic storage. You should use dynamic or static storage. Here is a fix to your code using static storage

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ASIZE 1000

long matrixa [ASIZE][ASIZE];
long matrixb [ASIZE][ASIZE];
long matrixc [ASIZE][ASIZE]; //set to zero by default with static storage

int main() {
    for(int i=0; i<ASIZE; i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<ASIZE; j++) {
            matrixa [i][j] = 1;
            matrixb [i][j] = j;
        }
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0 ;i<ASIZE; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<ASIZE; j++) {
            long sum = 0;
            for(int k=0; k<ASIZE; k++) {
                sum += matrixa[i][k]*matrixb[k][j];
            }
            matrixc[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) printf("Snap of C array %lu \n", matrixc[1][i]);
}
```

If you want a statically allocated buffer for each thread then you need to use `threadprivate` otherwise use dynamic allocation.

The reason you don't need to use a barrier is that a barrier is implicit with `critical` and many other constructs. To remove the implicit barrier you can use `nowait` in some cases (e.g. `#pragma omp parallel for nowait`).

Comment: could you explain a little bit about automatic storage? is all the global variable go this way by default?  and when you say"statically allocated buffer", do.you mean the cprivate matrix I used? It is called statically allocated because of I declare.the matrix with the matrix size directly?

Comment: Automatic storage uses the stack which has a limited size. In your code `matrixa, matrixb, matric, cprivate` all allocate from the stack. Global variables and variables defined using the static keyword use static storage.

Comment: There is no need for `cprivate` which is why I removed it. However, if you really want a private buffer for each thread then you should use `malloc` to allocate using the heap or `threadprivate` for static storage for each thread.

Comment: @javarookie, the reason I used static allocation is just so I chould use your same notation. Otherwise with dynamic allocation you have to do e.g. `matrixa[i*ASIZE+k]*matrixb[k*ASIZE+j]`.